# PHP - Insert column in CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I want to add new record / values in the first column with Column name of the existing CSV file in PHP. Eg:

Below is my existing CSV file.

[image]

After Insertion the CSV file look like :

[image]

So can you please guide me with the code.

Comment: Show us your code first

Comment: $fp = fopen("upload/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]."", 'a');     fputcsv($fp, array($supp,$inv,$st));     fclose($fp); 
This is the code that I tried.

Comment: read about file_get_contents() and file_put_contents()

Comment: You should really try by yourself, before asking here about solutions...

Answer (score 0):

You basically:

1. read the old CSV (maybe to array, see function `file`)
2. open and write a new CSV (with temporary name) with extra columns (`fopen`, `fputcsv`)
3. close file(s) (`flose`)
4. delete old CSV (`unlink`)
5. rename new CSV with old name (`rename`)

Comment: Thanks.. but can you please tell me how I can add the Column name. ?

Comment: You can do it with `fputcsv`. Just put the columns in the array (and to first line, probably). Just treat columns like any other data.